# Create a saved search with sales orders containing only two types of items

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create a saved search to show only the sales orders that have BOTH types of items on them.

Let's say I have:

ITEM TYPE A
ITEM TYPE B

These are checkboxes on the Item Record. An item can only be checked once.. either TYPE A or TYPE B.

I'd like a search that shows me all sales orders that how items on it that contain both ITEM TYPE A and ITEM TYPE B on it.

Right now I have a search with the following criteria (image attached). However, what it yields is only Sales Orders with items, where the the item's record has BOTH checkboxes checked on them.

How to make it to show what I need? Many thanks.

[saved search criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT22c.png)

Comment: Please clarify what you want.  I'm confused by "I'd like a search that shows me all sales orders that how items on it that contain both ITEM TYPE A and ITEM TYPE B on it." and "However, what it yields is only Sales Orders with items, where the the item's record has BOTH checkboxes checked on them".

Comment: sorry I thought this was a specific Netsuite section so did not add to the title.. and couldn't figure out how to edit it.

I'm looking for NetSuite help to create a saved search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use grouping and summary criteria (or SuiteScript).
Try Summary Criteria: Minimum formulanumeric MAX(DECODE({type_a_field},'T',1,0))+MAX(DECODE({type_b_field},'T',1,0)) equalto 2
and group the transaction. If you need to see each line item, use NS_CONCAT in a Minimum formulatext (or SuiteScript)